# Converting float to integer based on the result of join in python with panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I am doing a left and right join to get my data. Now I want to concatenate a fixed text which is "Hello/ProductID=" with the result of my join which must be integer. I don't know why the value which I got as the result is float?
As this is my URL I need to convert it to Integer:

```
df = df.join(df.set_index(['ID','Type'])['ProductID'].rename('PID'), on=['ID','UniqueCode'])
df["URL"]= "Hello/ProductID=" + df['PID'].apply(str)
```

The real result is as below:

```
Hello/ProductID=1221.0
```

My expected result should be as below:

```
Hello/ProductID=1221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating the condition and it is beacause `PID` is of `float` type. You may have to convert it to an `integar` type to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I used replace method to remove .0:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('\.0$', ' ')
```